# Resize grid causing issues. (etch-a-sketch TOP)

Tags: javascript, css

Doing the etch-a-sketch project for the odin project and I've got the grid itself working ok so long as it stays at the default size. When I try to use the setSize function though, it tends to push all the divs upwards in the container and I'm not sure how to solve that issue. It's especially obvious when resizing to a larger than 16x16 grid.

[Code pen link](https://codepen.io/BigSlyph/pen/gOQpdMR)

html:

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ETCH-A-SKETCH</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Etch-a-Sketch</h1>

 <div class="content">
    <div class="buttonCon">
        <div class="buttons">
         <button id="eraser">Eraser</button>
         <button id="reset">Reset</button>
         <button id="setSize">Set Size</button>
         <button id="pink">Pink</button>
        </div>
       </div>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
    
 </div>
 <div class="footer">
    ❤️ BigSlyphhh ❤️
  </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="java.js"></script>
</body>
</html>```

javascript:

``~

const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const eraser = document.getElementById("eraser");
const size = document.getElementById("setSize");
const pink = document.getElementById("pink");
const reset = document.getElementById("reset");



function createGrid(size){
  container.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
  container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;

  for (let i = 0 ; i < (size*size); i++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    cell.style.border = "white solid 0.1px";
    container.appendChild(cell);

    cell.addEventListener('mouseover', e=> {
      cell.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
    })

    eraser.addEventListener('click', e=> {
      cell.addEventListener('mouseover', e=> {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      })
    })
    pink.addEventListener('click', e=> {
      cell.addEventListener('mouseover', e=> {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
      })
    })

    function resetGrid(){
      reset.addEventListener('click', e=>{
        cell.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        
      })
    }

    resetGrid()
  }
}

createGrid(16)



function setSize () {
  let x = prompt("What size grid? (Up to 100)")
  container.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
  container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
  if (x > 100){
    alert("Must be 100 or less")
  } 
  else {
    createGrid(x)
  }
}


size.addEventListener('click', e =>{
  setSize()
})
````

Css:

```
html {
  background-color: rgb(248, 222, 226);
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: CerebriSans-Regular,-apple-system,system-ui,Roboto,sans-serif;
  
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  display: grid;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 4px solid rgb(244, 215, 215);
  border-radius: 5px;
}


h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: white;
  font-size: 55px;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
}
  


.buttonCon {
  width: 200px;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  border:4px rgb(244, 215, 215) solid;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* CSS for button design from cssscan, edited to suit color-scheme*/
button {
  background-color: pink;
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-shadow: rgba(252, 196, 246, 0.657) 0 -25px 18px -14px inset,rgba(245, 202, 237, 0.948) 0 1px 2px,rgb(238, 185, 234) 0 2px 4px,rgb(255, 185, 235) 0 4px 8px,rgba(241, 192, 230, 0.484) 0 8px 16px,rgb(255, 220, 254) 0 16px 32px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: CerebriSans-Regular,-apple-system,system-ui,Roboto,sans-serif;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 250ms;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 6px;
  
}

button:hover {
  box-shadow: rgb(238, 173, 230) 0 -25px 18px -14px inset,rgba(248, 186, 237, 0.948) 0 1px 2px,rgb(255, 177, 250) 0 2px 4px,rgb(244, 171, 223) 0 4px 8px,rgb(203, 163, 194) 0 8px 16px,rgb(242, 202, 241) 0 16px 32px;
  transform: scale(1.05) rotate(-1deg);
}

.footer {
  color: white;
}
```

javascript:

```
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const eraser = document.getElementById("eraser");
const size = document.getElementById("setSize");
const pink = document.getElementById("pink");
const reset = document.getElementById("reset");



function createGrid(size){
  container.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
  container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;

  for (let i = 0 ; i < (size*size); i++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    cell.style.border = "white solid 0.1px";
    container.appendChild(cell);

    cell.addEventListener('mouseover', e=> {
      cell.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
    })

    eraser.addEventListener('click', e=> {
      cell.addEventListener('mouseover', e=> {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      })
    })
    pink.addEventListener('click', e=> {
      cell.addEventListener('mouseover', e=> {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
      })
    })

    function resetGrid(){
      reset.addEventListener('click', e=>{
        cell.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        
      })
    }

    resetGrid()
  }
}

createGrid(16)



function setSize () {
  let x = prompt("What size grid? (Up to 100)")
  container.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
  container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
  if (x > 100){
    alert("Must be 100 or less")
  } 
  else {
    createGrid(x)
  }
}


size.addEventListener('click', e =>{
  setSize()
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start you create 16x16 divs.

Then when the user types in a new size you create even more divs which get added onto the end of the existing ones.

say the user asks for a grid of 20. You end up with 1616 + 20x20 divs.

But the CSS grid has only 20 rows, so the last 16x16 divs don't have proper grid cell height. But they have been given borders. So they are visible, or at least their borders are. Try making the border color red and you will see the red strip at the bottom of the grid.

So, remove the divs that already exist before creating any new ones.

This snippet just does it lazily by emptying the containers innerHTML as a demo.

```html
<style>
  html {
    background-color: rgb(248, 222, 226);
  }
  
  body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: CerebriSans-Regular, -apple-system, system-ui, Roboto, sans-serif;
  }
  
  .content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .container {
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
    display: grid;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 4px solid rgb(244, 215, 215);
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    font-size: 55px;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
  }
  
  .buttonCon {
    width: 200px;
    height: 90px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 4px rgb(244, 215, 215) solid;
  }
  
  .footer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  /* CSS for button design from cssscan, edited to suit color-scheme*/
  
  button {
    background-color: pink;
    border-radius: 100px;
    box-shadow: rgba(252, 196, 246, 0.657) 0 -25px 18px -14px inset, rgba(245, 202, 237, 0.948) 0 1px 2px, rgb(238, 185, 234) 0 2px 4px, rgb(255, 185, 235) 0 4px 8px, rgba(241, 192, 230, 0.484) 0 8px 16px, rgb(255, 220, 254) 0 16px 32px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: CerebriSans-Regular, -apple-system, system-ui, Roboto, sans-serif;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 250ms;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 6px;
  }
  
  button:hover {
    box-shadow: rgb(238, 173, 230) 0 -25px 18px -14px inset, rgba(248, 186, 237, 0.948) 0 1px 2px, rgb(255, 177, 250) 0 2px 4px, rgb(244, 171, 223) 0 4px 8px, rgb(203, 163, 194) 0 8px 16px, rgb(242, 202, 241) 0 16px 32px;
    transform: scale(1.05) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  
  .footer {
    color: white;
  }
</style>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ETCH-A-SKETCH</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Etch-a-Sketch</h1>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="buttonCon">
      <div class="buttons">
        <button id="eraser">Eraser</button>
        <button id="reset">Reset</button>
        <button id="setSize">Set Size</button>
        <button id="pink">Pink</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    ❤️ BigSlyphhh ❤️
  </div>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="java.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
<script>
  const container = document.querySelector(".container");
  const eraser = document.getElementById("eraser");
  const size = document.getElementById("setSize");
  const pink = document.getElementById("pink");
  const reset = document.getElementById("reset");



  function createGrid(size) {
    container.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
    container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
    container.innerHTML = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < (size * size); i++) {
      let cell = document.createElement("div");
      cell.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      cell.style.border = "white solid 0.1px";
      cell.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
      container.appendChild(cell);

      cell.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
      })

      eraser.addEventListener('click', e => {
        cell.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
          cell.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        })
      })
      pink.addEventListener('click', e => {
        cell.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
          cell.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
        })
      })

      function resetGrid() {
        reset.addEventListener('click', e => {
          cell.style.backgroundColor = "white";

        })
      }

      resetGrid()
    }
  }

  createGrid(16)



  function setSize() {
    let x = prompt("What size grid? (Up to 100)")
    container.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
    container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
    if (x > 100) {
      alert("Must be 100 or less")
    } else {
      createGrid(x)
    }
  }


  size.addEventListener('click', e => {
    setSize()
  })
</script>
```